# Why does new and malloc output different results?

Tags: c++, memory-management, malloc, new-operator

This is my code;

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int MIN(int a, int b)
{
    if (a <= b) return a;
    else return b;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a; 
    scanf("%d", &a);

    int *n = new int[a];
    //int *n = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*(a));
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        n[i] = a;

    n[a] = 0;

    for (int i = a; i > 1; i--)
    {
        if (i % 3 == 0) n[i / 3] = MIN(n[i] + 1, n[i / 3]);
        else if (i % 2 == 0) n[i / 2] = MIN(n[i] + 1, n[i / 2]);
        n[i - 1] = MIN(n[i] + 1, n[i - 1]);
    }

    printf("%d", n[1]);

    delete[] n;
    //free(n);
    return 0;
}
```

If you use `new`, nothing happens.

However, using `malloc` will cause a heap corruption detected error.

I wonder why this is happening and what's different from `new` and `malloc`.

Comment: `n[a] = 0;` is an out of bounds access and undefined behavior.

Comment: *"heap corruption detected"*  sounds like Visual C++ with the `/MTd` flag (read: "Debug mode"). But you should get that same error message with `new` as well. Are you sure you don't get it either way?

Comment: Use std::vector with push_back and iterators. Use std::min. Use iostreams. Don’t write C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n[a] = 0;
```

this line and further accessing the element in the array `n` with the index `a` causes undefined behavior, that is why the program crashes sometimes.

If you need to process the element with the index `a`, then allocate enough memory for that:

```
int *n = new int[a + 1];
```

Comment: Oh, right. I made a mistake.
thank you for your kind answer

Answer (score 2):

`n[a] = 0;` is an Undefined behavior. Even if you use `malloc` it is undefined behavior. And it is logical to stop reasoning the undefined behavior given that they are undefined and not depenedent on the function used or anything you might think of.

Accessing array index out of bound is undefined behavior.

Also if you are using `scanf` use it properly - the result that `scanf` returns should be checked to know whether it is successful or not.

Note that , your idea of that using `new` and `malloc` is creating differemt behavior is wrong. This is one of the things with udnefined behavior. It might work also - but that doesn't mean that it would work definitively every single time. Be careful.

Also you can use `malloc` to allocate necessary amounts of memory. (Ofcourse you can do that with `new` too).

```
if( (n=malloc(sizeof(*n)*(a+1)))==NULL){
   perror("malloc");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

<sup>Allocated memory using `malloc` should only be freed using `free` and for `new` it would be `delete`. Otherwise it is erroneous.</sup>

Comment: Of course it's undefined behaviour. But I believe the OP compiles with Visual C++ and a debug runtime which should detect the heap corruption and display a nice error dialog box regardless of whether `new` or `malloc` is used. I thus suspect that the OP is mistaken and the error message appears either way.

Comment: @ChristianHackl.: To be honest not aware with Visual C++ environment - I compile with gcc's `g++` and it is seg fault in my case. But yes what you said is right I suppose. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score -3):

`new` and `malloc` output different results because one is C++ and the other is C. There is a whole different implementation of the two. See also the other answers that tell you your program has UB.

Comment: While it is definitively not advised to use `malloc()` in C++ code, it is not illegal either (you can for example use it with trivially copiable data types or in combination with a placement new).  I further fear that this answer does not provide any relevant explanation/solution for the problem described in the question.

Comment: @Christophe, I only say they are _completely different implementations_. Of course you can use them both, but don't mix them. Memory you got from `new` cannot be deallocated with `free` for example.

Comment: OP didn't mix them.  He/She used malloc/free, then new[]/delete[].  The problem was solely due to the UB spotted in the other answer.  ANd as UB means undefined, it turned out that it caused memory corruption that was spotted in one case and remained unspotted in the other case.